# increasing size of screen, and moving the virtual screen

Tags: linux, centos, screen, virtual

I have some probleme using xrandr.
I have a laptop on CentOS 6.3, and the resolution is 1600*900. I want to increase the resolution to have 1600*1000 because some soft I have to run on it can not ajust their size.
Therefore I created a new size of virtual screen 1900*1000 with

```
$ cvt 1900 1000
```

And then :

```
$ xrandr --newmode [...]
$ xrandr --addmode[...]
```

My problem is : the new resolution is created but when I use it, I have a part invisible and not accesible (100 pix) and I can not move the screen by "pushing" the end of the screen with the cursor.
How can I set up this last part ?
Thanks

Comment: Setting a virtual resolution that is larger than the physical resolution of your screen doesn't magically create additional pixels in your display panel. You can either deal with the scrolling, or set it to scale down to your actual resolution (which likely won't look as good as you would hope), or get the software manufacturer to fix their bad coding in their application... I understand many applications may need a minimum usable resolution, but one that high is still going to run into issues on older hardware...

Comment: Ok, I can't get the manufacturer to fix it, that's why I wanted to enlarge the virtual screen. The solution of scrolling is interesting, do you have some documentation/link on it ? Maybe I don't have the right words to search on google, but I don't find some..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do what I was looking for.
in a terminal :

```
xrandr --fb 1600x1000 --output LVDS --mode 1600x900 --panning 1600x1000
```

I saw it on this page :
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1139691

Comment: It can also be done via options in your `xorg.conf`.

Comment: I didn't have xorg.conf in the laptop.